# Sum Amounts from Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently summing across five columns that are of money data type. The columns Amount2, Amount3, Amount4, Amount5 need to have displayed as Rows with their sum showing accordingly.

Currently the results look like this on execution of the query:

[image]

but I need the results to be displayed like in this format:

[image]

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

I did try this but not managing to get it to work:

```
SELECT name, amount1, column
FROM
(
    select 
        Name,
        sum(Amount1) as Amount1,
        sum(Amount2) as Amount2,
        sum(Amount3) as Amount3,
        sum(Amount4) as Amount4,
        Sum(Amount5) as Amount5
    from 
        #temp
    group by
        Name
) d
UNPIVOT
(
  value
  for column in (Amount2,Amount3,Amount4,Amount5)
) unpiv;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 67
>   Incorrect syntax near 'd'.

Sample Data

```
Create table #temp
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Amount1 money,
    Amount2 money,
    Amount3 money,
    Amount4 money,
    Amount5 money 
)

insert into #temp
(
    Name,
    Amount1,
    Amount2,
    Amount3,
    Amount4,
    Amount5
)
SELECT
    'Test',
    1,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    4,
    NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Test1',
    1,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    5
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Test2',
    1,
    NULL,
    3,
    NULL,
    NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Test',
    1,
    2,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL

select 
    Name,
    sum(Amount1) as Amount1,
    sum(Amount2) as Amount2,
    sum(Amount3) as Amount3,
    sum(Amount4) as Amount4,
    Sum(Amount5) as Amount5
from 
    #temp
group by
    Name

drop table #temp
```

Comment: on your error, `column` is a reserve word. Please change to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `UNION ALL` for each type `Amount`

```
; with cte as
(
    select *
    from   #temp
)
select 
    Name,
    sum(Amount1) as Amount1
from 
    cte
group by
    Name

union all

select  'Amount2', sum(Amount2) from cte

union all

select  'Amount3', sum(Amount3) from cte

union all

select  'Amount4', sum(Amount4) from cte

union all

select  'Amount5', sum(Amount5) from cte
```

Comment: Would rather avoid UNION if possible as this is part of a massive query that I've just provided a simple example - could we do Unpivot?

Comment: you don't have to replace the `#temp` with your query. You can use `cte`. Updated the query to illustrate what i mean

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the simplest (and generally most efficient) method is `apply`:

```
select v.*
from (select Name,
             sum(Amount1) as Amount1,
             sum(Amount2) as Amount2,
             sum(Amount3) as Amount3,
             sum(Amount4) as Amount4,
             sum(Amount5) as Amount5
      from #temp t
      group by Name
     ) n cross apply
     (values (Name, Amount1),
             ('Amount2', Amount2),
             ('Amount3', Amount3),
             ('Amount4', Amount4),
             ('Amount5', Amount5)
     ) v(Name, Amount)
where v.Amount is not null;
```